# Getting the last inserted ID with expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the value of the last id insert in a table. How i can do this in mysql?
For eg : in db2 we have

```
SET var_ID = (SELECT ID FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT INTO val_CLIENT(E_VER, NAME, TYPE) VALUES(0, val_NAME, 502)));
```

The above statement needs to be converted into mysql. How can i do this?

Comment: you can use 2 sql , first insert and get last id then use in second sql

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Do your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO val_CLIENT(E_VER, NAME, TYPE) VALUES(0, val_NAME, 502);
```

Depending if you're doing it in a stored procedure, you will have to modify this, but if you're looking to select it.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `ID`;
```

To store it as a variable, you can use the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) statement.

```
SET @VarID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: So you are saying I have to insert after setting the value like:     SET @VarID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());            INSERT INTO val_CLIENT(E_VER, NAME, TYPE) VALUES(0, val_NAME, 502);

Comment: Once you insert a row into a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute (the specifics don't require this, but it's the common usage), you would use that to retrieve what that ID was. Likely for inserting additional records for a foreign key relationship etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your `ID` column is of type `AUTO_INCREMENT`, Use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp) after the `INSERT` statement

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID
```

However, for concurrent requests using same connection, this will lead into inconsistent result. In that case, the following query is a safe bet:

```
SELECT ID FROM val_CLIENT 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible query:

SELECT id FROM `table`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: This assumes there are no race conditions (ie that someone else didn't already execute another `INSERT`).